# Python XML Data With BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml

Ok I'm having trouble filtering out some XML data with Beautiful Soup.

Here is the XML data:

```
<ticket>
<id>123456789</id>
<create_date>2017-12-09</create_date>
- <correspondence>
   - <diary_entry>
     - <user>username</user>
     - <timestamp>2017-12-09</timestamp>
     - <body>A bunch of text in here
          a lot of text
          more text
     - </body>
   - </diary_entry>
- </correspondence>
- <work_log>
   - <diary_entry>
     - <user>someotheruser</user>
     - <timestamp>2017-12-09</timestamp>
     - <body>Some more text in here
             and other text
     - </body>
   - </diary_entry>
- </work_log>
</ticket
```

I'm trying to get only values in the correspondence/diary_entry/body section, but my code keeps also providing values in the worklog/diary_entry/body section. Here is my current code:

```
ticket_url = "https://somelink/tickets/123456789"
    r = requests.get(ticket_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'xml')
    updates = soup.findAll('body')
    for update in updates:
        if "next steps:" not in update.text.lower():
            print "no"
            print update.text.lower()
        else:
            print "yes"
```

I'm not sure how to filter it down to only get the `<correspondence><body>` values. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one set of 'correspondence' and 'body' in ticket, you can chain the find command:

```
update = soup.find('correspondence').find('body')
```

otherwise you will have to iterate using find_all (Beautiful Soup 4) or findAll (Beautiful Soup 3):

```
correspondences = soup.find_all("correspondence")
for correspondence in correspondences:
    updates = correspondence.find_all("body")
    for update in updates:
    .....
```